# Static Way to Access a Remote Machine

Tags: sockets, server, client, ip-address, communication

There's an application. This application is run on several different client devices and it makes use of a server: that is, each of those instances of the application may connect to a server, said server being a certain remote machine that is constantly listening for incoming connections, at which point the client machine and the server machine communicate following a certain protocol.

Now, this is all nice and easy as long as I'm testing within one LAN managed by one router. I can simply set the server machine to have a static IP address and this address will just be hardcoded into the application so that every instance of it will be able to directly communicate with the server endpoint. But what I'm not sure about is what I'd do if this application was intended to run outside the limits of a single LAN with private IP addresses.

**Basically, my question is** what approach should I choose in order to have a static way to access a specific remote machine.
Is there any static public address that can be used to reach it? Or should I purchase a domain name and have it respond to requests from clients with the server machine's current public IP address? Or should I go on and purchase a static external IP address? Or am I simply not thinking about this the right way, and the solution should be approached from an entirely different direction?

Comment: As a sidenote, I'm sure there is an answer to this somewhere on SE, and I probably simply failed to find the proper keywords to search for it... Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Why not contract to have the server hosted by a hosting service?

Comment: @RonMaupin This would have been a possibility, but the client is quite intent on using a specific computer in his ownership as the server machine. I suppose in the very least I'd like to be able to tell him what his options are in this case.

Comment: You are going to need to deal with the ISP. Either get some addresses from the ISP, or get some on the market and set up routing (BGP) with the ISP to advertise those addresses. ISPs won't advertise a block of addresses smaller than `/24`. The last I heard addresses were going for more $10 an address, but that was before ARIN ran out of addresses to assign. Using the ISP's addresses will tie you to that ISP so that a change in ISPs will force a change of addressing. The whole hosting market was designed around doing this all for you.